# How to see which function a dll (c) exe calls?

Tags: windows, function, dll, reverse-engineering

I have exe(from c) that call some function on dll.

How can i see(onRuntime) which function on dll it go and which parameters it send?)

Answer (score 2):

[API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor). If the DLL is a part of windows, it will have the function definition. If not, you can write your own DLL function definitions and get it to list the calls for you.

You don't have function definition? it is Reverse Engineering time.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'd need a debugger, like OllyDbg or x64dbg.

Load your program into debugger and place breakpoints on every DLL export, then run your executable.

Another way is to hijack DLL by writing a wrapper, but that's much more tedious task.